# How can I simulate a failure of rand.Reader for testing purposes?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, runtime-error

I am trying to write a unit test for my function; note that it calls `rand.Read` (from [the crypto/rand package](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand)), which relies on [`rand.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand#Reader):

```golang
func GenerateBytes(length int) ([]byte, error) {
    bytes := make([]byte, length)
    if _, err := rand.Read(bytes); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return bytes, nil
}
```

I am able to write tests for the happy path, but I'm unable to test the case where `rand.Read` returns an error... Is there a way to simulate a failure of `rand.Read`?

Comment: @blackgreen The OP is likely referring to crypto/rand.

Comment: "is there any way to simualte error." assuming crypto/rand. But there is no need to. 100% line coverage just sounds like a good idea. It's not.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you trying to check? That, if `rand.Read` returns a non-nil error, then so does `GenerateBytes`? Are you simply trying to get the coverage percentage above some arbitrary threshold, or is such a check actually important to you? In the former case, please reconsider.

In the latter case, be aware that depending directly on package-level singletons like [`rand.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand#Reader) makes testing difficult. Improving testability requires some additional (but not prohibitive) effort.

### One possible approach

Thankfully, there's already a convenient interface that `rand.Reader` satisfies: [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader). If no such interface were already available, though, no biggie; you could have declared your own custom one. That's what's great about Go interfaces' implicit satisfaction!

Choose a way to pass an `io.Reader` to `GenerateBytes`. The most idiomatic way is to declare `GenerateBytes`, not as a top-level function, but as a method on some custom struct type (named `SourceOfRandomness` below) that has a (possibly anonymous) `io.Reader` field:

```golang
type SourceOfRandomness struct {
    Reader io.Reader
}
```

Doing so allows you to choose which `io.Reader` implementor to *inject* at instantiation of your custom type. `GenerateBytes` can then access the `io.Reader` it needs through its receiver:

```golang
func (sor *SourceOfRandomness) GenerateBytes(length int) ([]byte, error) {
    bytes := make([]byte, length)
    if _, err := sor.Reader.Read(bytes); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return bytes, nil
}
```

Then, in your production code, you'd initialise a `SourceOfRandomness` value with the actual `rand.Reader`:

```golang
sor := SourceOfRandomness{Reader: rand.Reader}
sor.GenerateBytes(42)
```

For the specific test case you had in mind, you can simply leverage (as mentioned by [mh-cbon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4466350/mh-cbon) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659292/is-there-any-way-to-unit-test-rand-reader-error-case/71659662?noredirect=1#comment126648220_71659662)) [`iotest.ErrReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/testing/iotest#ErrReader), which returns an `io.Reader` whose `Read` method unconditionally fails:

```golang
import (
  "crypto/rand"
  "testing/iotest"
)

func TestGenerateBytesFails(t *testing.T) {
  // Arrange
  sor := SourceOfRandomness{
    Reader: iotest.ErrReader(errors.New("oops"))
  }
  const dummyLength = 42
  // Act
  _, err := sor.GenerateBytes(dummyLength)
  // Assert
  if err != nil {
    t.Error("want non-nil error; got nil error")
  }
}
```

Comment: `RandReader` is an `io.Reader`, and thus, it is possible to leverage those apis https://pkg.go.dev/testing/iotest#ErrReader

Comment: @mh-cbon Nice, thanks! How am I only discovering this package now!?

Comment: @mh-cbon I'm also realising now that my `RandReader` interface is completely superfluous.

Comment: yep i agree to that, but it is a little issue. My understanding is that it is a common pitfall in the language to redefine an exiting interface because it takes time to learn the api and figure its internal compatibilities. Though, yes, that testing package really worth to be more well known.