# Go create a mock for gcp compute sdk

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dependency-injection, interface

I use the following function, and I need to **raise** the coverage of it (if possible to 100%), the problem is that typically I use `interface` to handle such cases in Go and for this specific case not sure how to do it, as this is a bit more **tricky**, any idea?

`The package` https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1

Which I use doesn't have `interface` so not sure how can I mock it?

```
import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    compute "cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    computev1 "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
)

func Res(ctx context.Context, project string, region string,vpc string,secret string) error {

    c, err := compute.NewAddressesRESTClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(secret))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer c.Close()
    addrReq := &computev1.ListAddressesRequest{
        Project: project,
        Region:  region,
    }
    it := c.List(ctx, addrReq)

    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if *(resp.Status) != "IN_USE" {
            return ipConverter(*resp.Name, vpc)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You can adapt the ideas laid out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659292/how-can-i-simulate-a-failure-of-rand-reader-for-testing-purposes/71659662#71659662

Comment: @jub0bs - thanks, but not sure how it's related as here I didnt find interface to mock, can you please provide the same way for my contexts ?

Comment: Does `secret` change at each invocation of `Res`? Or could the client be the same from one invocation of `Res` to the next?

Comment: @jub0bs - yes, the secret could be changed...

Comment: You should all the relevant imports. For example, what `computev1` is supposed to be isn't entirely clear.

Comment: @jub0bs - done, as you request, the import was added, im using the latest version of each of the OS

Comment: Can you please clarify how often the `secret` changes? Is it likely to change during the lifetime of your program?

Comment: @jub0bs - no it doesnt change during life time of the program , however diffrent invocation can have diff secret . does it  answer your question ?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's going to simplify things :)

Comment: @jub0bs - what you suggest ?

Comment: I'll have more time to post an answer later today :)

Comment: @jub0bs, Thank you! when running the code I got error in line `compute.NewAddressesRESTClient` I should not mock it? as the "serviceAccount" should always be fake in the test... how can I run it as test e2e, could you please provide an example?

Comment: I don't get any error. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obstacle to testability here is that you instantiate a client inside your `Res` function rather than injecting it. Because

- the secret doesn't change during the lifetime of the programme,
- the methods of `*compute.AddressesClient` (other than `Close`) are concurrency-safe,

you could create one client and reuse it for each invocation or `Res`. To inject it into `Res`, you can declare some `Compute` type and turn `Res` into a method on that type:

```
type Compute struct {
  Lister Lister // some appropriate interface type
}

func (cp *Compute) Res(ctx context.Context, project, region, vpc string) error {
addrReq := &computev1.ListAddressesRequest{
        Project: project,
        Region:  region,
    }
    it := cp.Lister.List(ctx, addrReq)
    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if *(resp.Status) != "IN_USE" {
            return ipConverter(*resp.Name, vpc)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

One question remains: how should you declare `Lister`? One possibility is

```golang
type Lister interface {
    List(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) *compute.AddressIterator
}
```

However, because `compute.AddressIterator` is a struct type with some unexported fields and for which package `compute` provides no factory function, you can't easily control how the iterator returned from `List` behaves in your tests. One way out is to declare an additional interface,

```golang
type Iterator interface {
    Next() (*computev1.Address, error)
}
```

and change the result type of `List` from `*compute.AddressIterator` to `Iterator`:

```golang
type Lister interface {
    List(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) Iterator
}
```

Then you can declare another struct type for the real `Lister` and use that on the production side:

```golang
type RealLister struct {
    Client *compute.AddressesClient
}

func (rl *RealLister) List(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) Iterator {
    return rl.Client.List(ctx, req, opts...)
}

func main() {
    secret := "don't hardcode me"
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background()) // for instance
    defer cancel()
    c, err := compute.NewAddressesRESTClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(secret))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // or deal with the error in some way
    }
    defer c.Close()
    cp := Compute{Lister: &RealLister{Client: c}}
    if err := cp.Res(ctx, "my-project", "us-east-1", "my-vpc"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // or deal with the error in some way
    }
}
```

For your tests, you can declare another struct type that will act as a configurable *test double*:

```golang
type FakeLister func(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) Iterator

func (fl FakeLister) List(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) Iterator {
    return fl(ctx, req, opts...)
}
```

To control the behaviour of the `Iterator` in your test, you can declare another configurable concrete type:

```golang
type FakeIterator struct{
    Err error
    Status string
}

func (fi *FakeIterator) Next() (*computev1.Address, error) {
    addr := computev1.Address{Status: &fi.Status}
    return &addr, fi.Err
}
```

A test function may look like this:

```golang
func TestResStatusInUse(t *testing.T) {
    // Arrange
    l := func(_ context.Context, _ *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, _ ...gax.CallOption) Iterator {
        return &FakeIterator{
            Status: "IN_USE",
            Err:    nil,
        }
    }
    cp := Compute{Lister: FakeLister(l)}
    dummyCtx := context.Background()
    // Act
    err := cp.Res(dummyCtx, "my-project", "us-east-1", "my-vpc")
    // Assert
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, im trying to debug it to learn from this example, the code doesnt compile , the error is for `cp := Compute{Lister: &RealLister{Client: c}}` error is `Cannot use '&RealLister{Client: c}' (type *RealLister) as the type ListerType does not implement 'Lister'need the method: List(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) *compute.AddressIteratorhave the method: List(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) Iterator`

Comment: i've changed it to `func (rl *RealLister) List(ctx context.Context, req *computev1.ListAddressesRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) *compute.AddressIterator {`

Comment: it would be great if you will provide the full files, the main and the test.

Comment: This is the function test *could you show please* how to mock and check it?  this is the only thing that im struggling with , https://go.dev/play/p/tNNPsS_PKBI

Comment: @JDC I'll update my answer later. In the meantime, check out this repo: https://github.com/jub0bs/so-question-72046805

Comment: I had a little trouble following this since I'm new to Go. However, with help, I got it and extended the concept to cover all such APIs from GCP containing an iterator in a generic fashion. Take a look at my blog post on the topic.
https://www.jackpines.info/2022/10/mocking-gcp-apis-containing-iterator.html

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I find myself in this scenario, I found that the easiest solution is to create *missing* interfaces myself. I limit these interfaces to the types and functions that I am using, instead of writing interfaces for the entire library. Then, in my code, instead of accepting third-party concrete types, I accept my interfaces for those types. Then I use gomock to generate mocks for these interfaces as usual.

The following is a descriptive example inspired by your code.

```golang
type RestClient interface {
    List(context.Context, *computev1.ListAddressesRequest) (ListResult, error) // assuming List returns ListResult type.
    Close() error
}

func newRestClient(ctx context.Context, secret string) (RestClient, error) {
    return compute.NewAddressesRESTClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(secret))
}

func Res(ctx context.Context, project string, region string, vpc string, secret string) error {
    c, err := newRestClient(ctx, secret)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer c.Close()
    return res(ctx, project, region, vpc, c)
}

func res(ctx context.Context, project string, region string, vpc string, c RestClient) error {
    addrReq := &computev1.ListAddressesRequest{
        Project: project,
        Region:  region,
    }

    it, err := c.List(ctx, addrReq)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if *(resp.Status) != "IN_USE" {
            return ipConverter(*resp.Name, vpc)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Now you can test the important bits of the `Res` function by injecting a mock `RestClient` to the internal `res` function.

Comment: Close, but you can't test the exported API (`Res`) that way.

Comment: @jub0bs and why would I want to test a piece of code that is so simple that its test case would need modification every time it changes? https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html

Comment: I simply favour _black-box testing_ (i.e. testing stuff through its public API), that's all.

Comment: The problem here isn't the testing approach, it's the way the code is written. The function under test creates its dependencies, rather than accepting them from the caller. You can move that part around, but the dependency instantiation part is simply untestable (in most cases including this one).

Comment: Thanks, how can I run it e2e with the test, can you please provide the full example?

Comment: End-to-end tests are both tricky and subjective. For example, do you want to mock Google Compute API, or do you want to test it with a fake API server? In any case, you'll need to restructure your code such that: a. `Res` accepts the RestClient from its caller so you can inject the mock or instantiate a real client with a fake server. b. You need to be able to control how RestClient is instantiated in different environments, i.e. during tests and production.

Comment: there is no problem to restructure the code to make it more clean, if you have suggestion please share it

Comment: @jub0bs already shared a comprehensive version of what I am suggesting.